# vim is ignoring configurations

Tags: macos, vim, vimrc

Vim is just not applying some configuration statements. This behaivior started after I installed a plugin to it, and updated MacOS (that shouldn't be related to each other !?).

One example is textwidth. I've set it to 60 in my vimrc and apparently its not overwritten elsewhere.

`:verbose set textwidth?`

returns

```
  textwidth=60
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 10
```

So it **is** set. Still, it doesn't break a line, no matter how long it gets. There are more examples like autoindent for certain languages, but you see the problem already. It doesn't ignore everything though. Line numbers, laststatus for example work correctly.

Here's what I see:

```
  1 sfsldjflsjd klfsjd lfsdj fklsdj flksd jflksdj fklsdj fklsd df
  2 sdfjskdl jffjsldkj lskdj fklsdjf slkdj slkdj glkdj gkldfj glkdfj
  3
  4                        ! It should wrap the line about here ^
  5                        ! Instead a line goes on forerver like below, unless I manually break it
  6
  7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et     magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequ    at massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis     vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputa    te eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, fe    ugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curab    itur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, s    it amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tinci    dunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis le    o. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,sd    jfsjflsd
```

I uninstalled all plugins, an reinstalled vim alltogether. Still the same. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Vim version: 9.0

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Dec 19 2022 00:34:58)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-1023
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
-arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
-balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        -vartabs
+clipboard         -keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            -profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      -langmap           +python/dyn        +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          -rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildignore
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -X11
+digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xim
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
-emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

MacOS Version: BigSur 11.7.4

```
$ uname -a
Darwin my-host 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Fri Dec 16 00:35:00 PST 2022; root:xnu-7195.141.49~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please copy&paste all information directly to the question instead of using external servers. Show an example what text might already exist, what you type, the result you actually get and what you expect.

Comment: @Community

The problem is vim is ignoring configurations statements I've set in my vimrc. An example is the textwidth as described above. It seems to be set, but it is not applied. The text is not wrapped after 60 characters. I want vim to apply my configuration.

Comment: @bodo

I added the information to the question.

Comment: I meant to include *everything* in the question. Use code blocks for the "More detailed output." and "Uname". Show an exact example how you check that word-wrapping does not work or how you find out that other settings are ignored. Don't use comments to explain details, [edit] your question instead. Without a reproducible example you might not get an answer.

Comment: @Bodo

I edited the question. I hope its more comprehensible now.

Comment: And you are manually typing, not pasting the text?

Comment: @bodo

I am typing manually, not pasting. I pasted that blindtext, but continuing on that line doesn't break it. I could type a line of the same length, nothing happens.

Comment: *Please add all requested information or clarification to the question.* Show the output of `:set fo?`. Please copy&paste the whole `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So: Vim ignored the textwidth setting because `set paste` was set. Setting `set paste` disabled checking for the width of the line. Yet, I could not figure out why. Removing `set paste` from my config solved it.

That behaviour is not related to the Operating System in use.

Comment: Nice :-) It'd get even nicer if you [edited](https://superuser.com/posts/1773090/edit) the answer to explain which file exactly one needs to modify, what's the location of the file in MacOS and maybe even the entire config file to make it really clear.